# OCR batch processing tiff to text

Tags: batch-file, ocr, tiff, tesseract

I have a problem where i need to batch convert 50,000 tiff's into 50,000 txt files respectively. I am aware of abbyy finereader and some other pieces of software that may be able to do this, but a free solution would be best. I have been researching tesseract as well. Is anyone aware of any script or program that uses tesseract to do this automatically with a good quality output??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

For a free solution with Tesseract, here's a straightforward command line batch file. Change the variable contents and/or create folders as necessary:

```
:Start
   @Echo off
   Set _SourcePath=C:\tifs\*.tif
   Set _OutputPath=C:\txts\
   Set _Tesseract="C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"
:Convert
   For %%A in (%_SourcePath%) Do Echo Converting %%A...&%_Tesseract% %%A %_OutputPath%%%~nA
:End   
   Set "_SourcePath="
   Set "_OutputPath="
   Set "_Tesseract="
```

Comment: I have actually written a shell script to do it very simply in Linux. So now my problem is tesseract itself. For very "easy" examples it works just fine. But i am gettin a variety of errors for 1 in every 30 or so tiffs. e.g. "TIFF directory is missing required "stripbycounts" field". So I'm just googling them one by one to resolve them

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, I think Tesseract is going to give you the best results, whether you're looking at free solutions or not.

If you figure out how to convert one file, and then you post back the command you use, it will be easy to hack a batch script together to process multiple files.

Comment: What makes you think that tesseract will produce better results than commerial tools? Did you ever try to compare? Here you can find actual comparison: http://www.splitbrain.org/blog/2010-06/15-linux_ocr_software_comparison

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [VietOCR](http://vietocr.sf.net), a Java/.NET frontend for Tesseract; its function seems to suit your need.